# Сложение каждого элемента одного значения SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, суммирование

Есть таблица с 3 столбцами:

```
1. ID
2. IP
3. SumIP
```

Таблица:

```
ID   IP              SumIP
1.   192.168.1.1     152
2.   192.168.1.1     544
3.   192.168.64.23   975
...
```

Необходимо получить те IP, у которых выполняется условие, что сумма каждой цифры > SumIP (на примере первого IP):

```
//192.168.1.1
1+9+2+1+6+8+1+1 > SumIP
```

Как это возможно реализовать используя только sql?

Comment: СУБД уточните..

Comment: @teran СУБД MsSQL.

Comment: для ускорения, очевидно, из выборки можно отбросить все значения с `sumIP > 108`

Comment: а версия MS SQL-то какая?

Comment: даже не `108`, а `80`

Comment: @teran MS SQL server 17. Что касается отбрасывания sumIP - это можно, но значений не так много. Лучше бы их все проверить. На всякий слуйчай.

Comment: на какой такой всякий? у вас максимум 12 девяток может быть, но при условии что в ip-адресе первая максимум двойка, то максимальная сумма может быть 4*(2+9+9), хотя по факту даже еще меньше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько решение будет эффективно. Но первое,  как я уже отметил в комментариях, у вас даны 4 группы чисел по 3 цифры. То есть потенциально можно вписать `999.999.999.999`, что дает максимально возможную сумму равную 108. Далее, поскольку речь такие про ipv4 адрес, то первая цифра всегда будет максимум 2, так что упрощенно, можно взять максимальное значение `299.299.299.299` с суммой `80`. Правда зная, что фактически максимальное значение `255`, а максимальная сумма будет у `199`, то можно и еще сократить по единице.

Далее непосредственно к решению, хотя оно возможно и не очень эффективно. В 17й версии появилась функция `string_split`, которую мы можем использовать для разделения адреса по точке. Фактически это для решения и не требуется (мб даже усложнит его).

Применив эту функцию к набору данных мы получим по 4 строки на каждую исходную. Далее чтобы получить сумму цифр каждого числа, можем воспользовать делением, или подстроками. Разделив число на 100, мы получим первое значение (деление целочисленное). Для десяткой и единиц можно использовать `substring()`.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT id, ip, v.value
      , cast(substring(v.value, 1,1) )as x
      , substring(v.value, 2,1) as y
      , substring(v.value, 3,1) as z
      , ipsum
    FROM ipdata
    CROSS APPLY string_split(ip, '.') as v
    WHERE ipsum <= 80
)    
SELECT id, min(ip), sum(x+y+z), min(ipsum)
FROM data
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(x+y+z) > min(ipsum)
```

Это, конечно,  несколько усложняет запрос, можно изначально напрямую сделать `replace` для точек в адресе и с помощью `substring` получить все 12 значений

```
with data as (
    select id, replace(ip, '.', '') as ip, ipsum         
   from ipdata
)
 select id, 
        cast(substring(ip, 1,1) as int)
        +substring(ip, 2,1)
        +substring(ip, 3,1)
        +substring(ip, 4,1)
        +substring(ip, 5,1)
        +substring(ip, 6,1)
        +substring(ip, 7,1)
        +substring(ip, 8,1)
        +substring(ip, 9,1)
        +substring(ip, 10,1)
        +substring(ip, 11,1)
        +substring(ip, 12,1) as s
       ,ipsum
 from data
```

[sql-фиддл](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1120f/30)

Comment: значений может быть не 12, а 4, если адрес имеет вид `1.1.1.1`

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший способ, если известено точное количество значений. К примеру, для даты mm.DD.yy отлично подайдёт.

Comment: @Lexx918 и чего? `substring` пустую строку вернут для несуществующих  индексов.

Comment: @NikoVashe добавил ссылку на фидл. Единственное что тут надо знать, что 12 значений максимум, сколько по факту не важно. и то для второго варианта. в первом нужно знать что 3 значения в группе.

Comment: @teran Спасибо! Действительно, это самая простая реализация, которая работает как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Такие суммы было бы лучше считать в момент вставки значения и сразу сохранять в соседнем поле таблицы. Но раз вы решили считать на лету, давайте считать на лету.

Первое, что нам надо сделать, это выделить каждую их 4х групп адреса. Для этого в SQL есть замечательная функция [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), которая может разбить строку на части по заданному символу, а потом вернуть такое число групп слева или справа, какое попросите. Если скомбинировать её и обрезать сначала левую часть до нужной группы, а потом оставлять крайнюю правую, то вот так можно выделить любую (в примере вторая):

```
-- вернёт 168
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('192.168.10.1', '.', 2), '.', -1)
```

Теперь каждую часть адреса надо сконвертировать из строки в число (беззнаковое):

```
-- превратит "168" (string) в 168 (int без знака)
cast('168' as UNSIGNED)
```

Далее самое сложное - выделяем из числа единицы, десятки и сотни. Если любое целое разделить по модулю на 10 (остаток от деления на 10), то получатся единицы:

```
-- вернёт 8
168 % 10
```

Если теперь от исходного числа отнять эти единицы, а результат разделить по модулю на 100, то получим десятки:

```
-- вернёт 60
(168 - (168 % 10)) % 100
```

Но нам нужны не десятки, а только их количество, поэтому делим десятки на 10, чтобы откинуть нолик в конце:

```
-- вернёт уже не 60, а 6
((168 - (168 % 10)) % 100) / 10
```

Тоже самое делаем с сотнями, вычитаем из исходного числа единицы и десятки, результат делим по модулю на 1000 и отбрасываем нули в конце делением на 100 (на самом деле деление по модулю тут не нужно т.к. в ip-адресе только 3 разряда на группу, но я оставил общее решение):

```
-- вернёт 1
((168 - (168 % 10) - ((168 - (168 % 10)) % 100)) % 1000) / 100
```

Так мы получим единицы, десятки и сотни одной части ip-адреса. Если сделать тоже самое для каждой группы, а потом всё сложить, - получится ожидаемый результат.

Осталось выделить в этом методе удобные лаконичные функции и использовать их, а не писать огромные страшные запросы каждый раз, но это вы можете и сами. Я же только приведу ниже сам запрос для отладки:

```
select ip, summ1 + summ2 + summ3 + summ4 as summ_all
from (
    select ip,
    cast(part1dig1 + part1dig2 + part1dig3 as UNSIGNED) summ1,
    cast(part2dig1 + part2dig2 + part2dig3 as UNSIGNED) summ2,
    cast(part3dig1 + part3dig2 + part3dig3 as UNSIGNED) summ3,
    cast(part4dig1 + part4dig2 + part4dig3 as UNSIGNED) summ4
    from (
        select ip,
        -- единицы, десятки и сотни
        part1int % 10 as part1dig1,
        ((part1int - (part1int % 10)) % 100) / 10 as part1dig2,
        ((part1int - (part1int % 10) - ((part1int - (part1int % 10)) % 100)) % 1000) / 100 as part1dig3,
        part2int % 10 as part2dig1,
        ((part2int - (part2int % 10)) % 100) / 10 as part2dig2,
        ((part2int - (part2int % 10) - ((part2int - (part2int % 10)) % 100)) % 1000) / 100 as part2dig3,
        part3int % 10 as part3dig1,
        ((part3int - (part3int % 10)) % 100) / 10 as part3dig2,
        ((part3int - (part3int % 10) - ((part3int - (part3int % 10)) % 100)) % 1000) / 100 as part3dig3,
        part4int % 10 as part4dig1,
        ((part4int - (part4int % 10)) % 100) / 10 as part4dig2,
        ((part4int - (part4int % 10) - ((part4int - (part4int % 10)) % 100)) % 1000) / 100 as part4dig3
        from (
            -- приводим тип числа в группе из строки к беззнаковому int'у
            select ip,
                cast(part1 as UNSIGNED) as part1int,
                cast(part2 as UNSIGNED) as part2int,
                cast(part3 as UNSIGNED) as part3int,
                cast(part4 as UNSIGNED) as part4int
            from (
                -- получение каждой из 4х групп адреса
                select ip,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 1), '.', -1) as part1,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 2), '.', -1) as part2,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 3), '.', -1) as part3,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 4), '.', -1) as part4
                from (
                    -- исходное значение
                    select '192.168.10.1' as ip
                ) raw_data
            ) ip_parts
        ) int_parts
    ) mods
) summs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(ip varchar(20),sumip int)
insert into @t values('192.168.1.1',     152),
('192.168.1.1',     544),
('192.168.64.23',   975);
with dsum as (select ip,sumip,
    (len(replace(ip,'9','xx'))-len(ip))*9+
    (len(replace(ip,'8','xx'))-len(ip))*8+
    (len(replace(ip,'7','xx'))-len(ip))*7+
    (len(replace(ip,'6','xx'))-len(ip))*6+
    (len(replace(ip,'5','xx'))-len(ip))*5+
    (len(replace(ip,'4','xx'))-len(ip))*4+
    (len(replace(ip,'3','xx'))-len(ip))*3+
    (len(replace(ip,'2','xx'))-len(ip))*2+
    (len(replace(ip,'1','xx'))-len(ip)) d from @t
    )
select ip from dsum
--where d>sumip;
```